# Iptables route localhost:3306 to remoteip:3306

Tags: mysql, iptables, routing, port

I have multiple websites connecting to `localhost` (default 3306 port) for mySQL. The plan is to dump and import on an external server `1.1.1.1` how can I temporarily route (until reboot) all `localhost:3306` traffic using IP tables to `1.1.1.1:3306`

I have tried

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to 2.2.2.2:3306
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 2.2.2.2 -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 2):

Please be aware that with MySQL on Linux `localhost` is special:

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name `localhost` specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs: the ***client connects using a Unix socket file***.
> ....
> For example, with `--host=localhost` on Unix, the client attempts to connect to the local server using a Unix socket file, even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a TCP/IP port number.
> <sub>https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting.html</sub>

In that case port forwarding  127.0.0.1:3306 to somewhere else is nice idea in theory, but won't actually help your applications. They are most likely not using TCP/IP to connect to 127.0.0.1:3306, they connect to the Unix socket the MySQL daemon provides.

Comment: Can you explain a little more why "Not using TCP/IP to connect to 127.0.0.1:3306" ? I don't normally connect via tcp/ip when i exchange traffic over localhost:3306, 127.0.0.1:3306, when i communicate as an example with php to mysql?

Comment: No. In addition to a network listener by default the MySQL server also creates a unix socket. (where depends a bit on the distribution but for example `/var/[ lib | run]/mysql/mysql.socket` )   Using a socket to connect to the MySQL offers a lot more performance (neither the MySQL server nor the client need to encode/decode traffic in TCP/IP packets for example) the communication between client and server happens directly in the kernel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket

Comment: This is interesting for a new post in advance ^^

Comment: There are heaps of Q&A's regarding the oddities of how MySQL treats localhost already.

Answer (score 0):

You need `route_localnet`  and should do first nat on the OUTPUT chain since the traffic is starting with a local process.

Try something like:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/route_localnet

iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -d 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1:3306 
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 1.1.1.1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Note that there is a security issue with this if your routing unencrypted mysql over the internet. Better if your on local network, or securing with VPN or mysql encrypted connections.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rinetd` for that purpose.

From `man rinetd`:

rinetd redirects TCP connections from one IP address and port to another. rinetd is a single-process server which handles any number of connections to the address/port pairs specified in the file /etc/rinetd.conf.

`rinetd` is available in most Linux distributions.